# trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied; `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256, H160, H64, ethereum_types::U256`

Tags: polkadot, rust, evm, frontier

Frontier(pallet-ethereum) project failed to compile after updating from polkadot-v0.9.17 to v0.9.18

```
    Compiling polkadot-runtime v0.9.18 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.18#9ed0c982)
   Compiling kusama-runtime v0.9.18 (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot?branch=release-v0.9.18#9ed0c982)
   Compiling p-chain-runtime v0.0.1 (/mnt/sda3/polkadot/1pchain/runtime)
    Checking ethereum v0.12.0
error[E0277]: the trait bound `H256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ethereum-0.12.0/src/header.rs:10:39
    |
10  |     derive(codec::Encode, codec::Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H256`
    |
note: required by a bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scale-info-2.1.1/src/build.rs:382:13
    |
382 |         TY: TypeInfo + 'static + ?Sized,
    |             ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `scale_info::TypeInfo` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `H160: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ethereum-0.12.0/src/header.rs:10:39
    |
10  |     derive(codec::Encode, codec::Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `H160`
    |
note: required by a bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scale-info-2.1.1/src/build.rs:382:13
    |
382 |         TY: TypeInfo + 'static + ?Sized,
    |             ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `scale_info::TypeInfo` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `Bloom: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ethereum-0.12.0/src/header.rs:10:39
    |
10  |     derive(codec::Encode, codec::Decode, scale_info::TypeInfo)
    |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for `Bloom`
    |
note: required by a bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scale-info-2.1.1/src/build.rs:382:13
    |
382 |         TY: TypeInfo + 'static + ?Sized,
    |             ^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `FieldBuilder::<N>::ty`
    = note: this error originates in the derive macro `scale_info::TypeInfo` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound `ethereum_types::U256: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> /home/user2038/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/ethereum-0.12.0/src/header.
```

My Rust tool-chain

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/user2038/.rustup
installed toolchains
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2021-09-10-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-2021-11-12-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
bpf
1.59.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)

active toolchain
1.59.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like mismatching versions.
`cargo tree -p scale-info` will show you.

ethereum-types has very permissive requirements for scale-info, so maybe a `cargo update -p scale-info` will fix the mismatch.

```
cargo tree
cargo tree -p scale-info:1.0.0
cargo tree -p scale-info:2.1.1

cargo update -p scale-info
cargo update -p scale-info:2.1.1
cargo update -p scale-info:1.0.0
```

https://github.com/paritytech/scale-info/issues/153